# How to filter out data between two columns?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003

I have data in my excel sheet in the below format

> A  B
>   1   2
>   2   3
>   3   5
>   4   8
>   5   
>   6   
>   7   
>   8   
>   9

i.e colA has values 1 through 9 and colB has 2,3,5,8. Now what I need in col C is, the data in colA which is not there in colB .

So my result column C should have

> C
>   1
> 4
> 6
> 7
> 9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've haven't got excel at this computer but the basic idea is to use

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A1, B:B, 0));A1;"")
```

I'll check if this works in a couple of hours.

Explanation: Set the value of the current cell to value of A1 if there exists no cell in column B that has value that is an exact match to the value of cell A1.

Documenation: [MATCH](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/excel-help/match-HP005209168.aspx), [ISNA](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/is-functions-HP005209147.aspx), [IF](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/if-HP005209118.aspx)

Comment: Yup. Seems to work. Though I'm using a localized version of excel in which the code looks like `=JOS(ONPUUTTUU(VASTINE(A2;B:B;0));A2;"")` where the row 1 contains the column headers.

Comment: Thank you very much Aleksi.. It did really worked.. Thanks alot